# Escaping passwords before http_build_query

Tags: php, curl

If a user password contain some special characters such as `$` the login would fail as `http_build_query` seems to break.I pass my POST variables like the following where

`curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($curl_parameters_array));`

How can i make sure that  the code will work fine even if user password contain special characters.

Comment: what do you mean, what is your array contains?

Comment: @monoir009 it contain username and password